# Tell if IIS is being asked to serve compressed pages?

Tags: iis-6, log-files, compression

I'm trying to find out if our IIS server is being asked to serve pages compressed. I'm a noob regarding a lot of this so am working my way through the issues.

We're using IIS 6.0 and have correctly turned compression on. If I use Fiddler2 to analyse the HTTP requests via localhost, then Fiddler reports that the pages are compressed.

If we then access the server over the network, either via its external URL or via the internal server name, Fiddler reports those pages as uncompressed.

Therefore, it's logical to assume that something is getting in the way - presumably our ISA server.

Our ISA administrator states that ISA is configured to allow compressed requests but what I want to do is to look at the requests coming through to IIS to see if IIS is being asked to serve pages compressed. I'm fairly convinced that our request is going to ISA, ISA is forwarding these, but not with the "compression" details - therefore IIS is not performing any compression.

I've looked at the IIS logs but can't see anything obvious about the HTTP request. Is there any way I can check, on the web server itself, this sort of information?

One thing that is confusing, but it may be normal, is that the Client IP making the request is not the orignal PC (i.e. mine) and not the ISA firewall, but the web server itself...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sniffer (like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) or the built-in Network Monitor in Windows) is your friend. There's no substitute for looking at the packets, especially when you've got a situation like this where you migth want to examine the traffic before ISA Server gets ahold of it and afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS logs, you are looking for the phrase "gzip". The column you are looking for the client ip is the c-ip. The logs do also contain the server's ip address. The client ip address is the 9th (ish) column along.

Have a look at [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) if you want to query the logs.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I've checked the text based IIS logs (..Windows\System32\logfiles) but no phrase gzip anywhere, but Fiddler is still saying the page is compressed and the IIS compression folder contains compressed files. Is there another log I should be looking at?